# Resilio package error prevents updates and most other terminal commands

Tags: updates

a new nwb here.
After unsuccesfully trying to install resilio-sync i started to get this kind of errors when trying to execute most of the most common commands at the Terminal. Because of this i cannot update ubuntu 16.04
Here a couple of errors from many. Similar errors i get when i try to autoremove or apt-get install -f, etc.

Can also not remove the resilio package.

Any clue on how to get ride of this anoying error????

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 oxideqt-codecs-extra
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up resilio-sync:armhf (2.4.4-1) ...
usermod: user 'rslsync' already exists
dpkg: error processing package resilio-sync:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resilio-sync:armhf


sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up resilio-sync:armhf (2.4.4-1) ...
usermod: user 'rslsync' already exists
dpkg: error processing package resilio-sync:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resilio-sync:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanx in advance, i hope this time i wont have to reinstall ubuntu again!!!

Comment: Looks like bug in the package post-installation script that you should report to its maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove it with

```
sudo apt purge resilio-sync
```